# Problem: this for condition should execute till the letter is vowel but why is it stopping after first iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, error-handling

```py
word=input("Enter a word: ")
W=word.upper()
V=['A','E','I','O','U']
W=list(W)
L=[]
print(W)
for i in W:
    if i not in V:
       L.append(i) 
       W.remove(i)
    else:
       break
print(L)
print(W)
```

Problem: this for condition should execute till the letter is vowel but why is it stopping after first iteration?

`I/P= black`
expected O/P:

```
['B','L']
['A','C','K']
```

actual o/p

```
['B']
['L','A','C','K']
```

Comment: You could use more descriptive variable names... For example, `vowels` instead of `V`, `letters` instead of `L`, do `word = word.upper()` instead of assigning it to a new (badly named) variable...

Comment: Probably because you are removing elements from the container you are iterating over. You're not iterating over the characters you are thinking. When you remove B, the next iteration will not get L but instead A, where the loop breaks.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal- Can you explain why it is not taking L?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are modifying `W` inside the loop and that is causing the skip. Change your `for-loop` to the snippet below. `W[:]` is besically a copy of your `W` list:

```py
for i in W[:]:
```

**Test code:**

```py
word=input("Enter a word: ")
W=word.upper()
V=['A','E','I','O','U']
W=list(W)
L=[]
print(W)
for i in W[:]:
    if i not in V:
       L.append(i) 
       W.remove(i)
    else:
       break
print(L)
print(W)
```

---

```
Enter a word: 
black
['B', 'L', 'A', 'C', 'K']
['B', 'L']
['A', 'C', 'K']
```